# Using nameof to access member of generic class without knowing the type

Tags: .net, nameof

Take these two classes:

```
class NonGenericClass
{
    public string Member { get; set; }
}

class GenericClass<T>
{
    public string Member { get; set; }
}
```

I can easily do this:

```
nameof(NonGenericClass.Member)
```

But I can't do this:

```
nameof(GenericClass.Member)
```

I could do this:

```
nameof(GenericClass<object>.Member)
```

But I don't want to.

Is there a way to do what I want without having to resort doing it in a way that I don't want to?

Comment: Well *why* don't you want to do `GenericClass<object>.Member`? I agree that it's annoying to have to specify a generic type argument (in a way that serves no purpose) but it does no actual harm.

Comment: @JonSkeet The rationale, I guess, is that if `T` has a type constraint and that constraint's type is ever removed from the assembly, the code will fail to build.  Maybe it's not a big deal to have to go specify a new generic type, but I am a set-it-and-forget-it kind of guy (like Ron Popeil), so I was hoping a better method exists

Comment: That would be a breaking change anyway, long before `nameof` gets involved... and it would be trivial to change the `nameof` usage. But no, there's no other way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way of using `nameof` for a generic type (or a member of that generic type) without specifying a type argument. I would personally *like* to be able to specify the open type as you can with `typeof`, i.e.

```
// Would be nice, but isn't valid
string name = nameof(GenericClass<>.Member);
```

... which would allow distinction between different generic types with different arities in the same way (`GenericClass<,>`, `GenericClass<,,>` etc) but that just isn't valid at the moment. There's already a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4827) for this which has some support, but it certainly won't be in C# 7, and I'd be surprised if it got in before C# 8 at best.

I suggest you just hold your nose and use `GenericClass<int>.Member` or similar. Any change that makes that break is likely to make far worse problems than this. If you're consistent about the type argument you use, a simple search and replace should fix it.

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried and was disappointed it didn't work.  No reason why they couldn't/shouldn't do it

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: I agree - feel free to add your voice to the linked feature request :)